# How to add a user control to populate records on a master-detail form?

Tags: forms, oracle, master-detail

Please help, Oracle form expert!

I created a master-detail form, and the user now wants to add a control to populate records on it--open items, closed items or all items.

I created a new Data Block that has one Item (Radio_Group), and laid out 3 Radio Buttons OPEN, CLOSED & ALL that should match a table column with values like 'Sent1, Sent2, Sent3, Reviewed' for OPEN, 'Rejected, Declined' for CLOSED and ALL should cover both of them.

On Radio_Group Property_Pallete, Item Type: Radio Group; Subclass Info:RADIO_GROUP; Mapping of Other Values: Open; & Initial Value: Open

For 3 Radio Buttons, Label & Radio Button Value are the same: Open, closed & ALL.

On the WHEN-RADIO-CHANGED, I wrote:

```
IF :RADIO_DISPLAY.DISPLAY = 'OPEN' THEN

   SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY('CCR_MANAG_MAIN', DEFAULT_WHERE,
     'upper(ISG_STATUS) like ''SEN%'' or upper(ISG_STATUS) like ''%REVIEW''');
   GO_BLOCK('CCR_MANAG_MAIN');
   CLEAR_FORM('NO_VALIDATE');
   execute_query;

IFELS upper(:RADIO_DISPLAY.DISPLAY) = upper('CLOSED') THEN
    SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY('CCR_MANAG_MAIN', DEFAULT_WHERE
      ,'upper(ISG_STATUS) not like ''SEN%'' and upper(ISG_STATUS) not like ''%REVIEW''');
    GO_BLOCK('CCR_MANAG_MAIN');
    CLEAR_FORM('NO_VALIDATE');
    execute_query;

ELSE
    SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY('CCR_MANAG_MAIN', DEFAULT_WHERE,'');
    GO_BLOCK('CCR_MANAG_MAIN');
    CLEAR_FORM('NO_VALIDATE');
    execute_query;
END IF;
```

No compiling errors but Radio Buttons are not working. What I missed? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your CLEAR_FORM('NO_VALIDATE');  is sending the cursor to the control block, then your execute_query is executed in the wrong block.

Try using CLEAR_BLOCK('NO_VALIDATE'); if clearing the fields is really necessary.

Comment: I was out of the country for 5 weeks and now come back to the project. Thank you Elias for answering my question. However I made the change and still not working. Anything else I need to check??

Comment: Welcome back, haha;

Well, about your problem: I'm not sure about what it really is, now. Is the query being executed? Check if you have any pre-query trigger messing with your query.

Also, you could check if the the query that is being created is coherent.

Comment: I've tried to put the code in pre-query (also in WHEN-NEW_FORM-INSTANCE) from WHEN-RADIO-CHANGED, but can not make it working. My goal is to give the user 3 choices to populate the master multiple records form: all items, open items and closed items that should based on the 3 select statements

Comment: select * from inds_ccr_manag_main;                   
                                                              select * from  inds_ccr_manag_main where upper(ISG_STATUS)       like 'SEN%'   or upper(ISG_STATUS)      like '%REVIEW';
                                                                    select * from  inds_ccr_manag_main where upper(ISG_STATUS) not like 'SEN%' and upper(ISG_STATUS) not like '%REVIEW';

Comment: Yes, Radio Group should work. So... is the query being executed or some error happens at runtime?

Comment: I gave up using Radio Group, and changed them to buttons with the same code. They work well. Thank you for your help, Elias.